# React Native Animated don't work on first click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated

I am creating a poker table using react native and I want that on the click of a chair animation should happen(arrangement of chairs around the table).

But animation does not work on clicking on the first time, while it works when I click 2nd time.

Please check the image below[image]

You can see there are 8 chairs around the table what I want is that whenever I click on any table, the rotation should take place in such a way that the table I clicked on should replace the green table(bottom)

The problem is that on the first click, the code inside useEffect works but still animation does not occur.

Here is the code

```js
import {
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

function HomeScreen() {
  const [shiftBy, setSiftBy] = React.useState(0);
  const [p1InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 180, y: 30 }));
  const [p2InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 325, y: 125 }));
  const [p3InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 338, y: 230 }));
  const [p4InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 335, y: 370 }));
  const [p5InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 180, y: 470 }));
  const [p6InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 30, y: 370 }));
  const [p7InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 30, y: 230 }));
  const [p8InitialPosition] = React.useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 40, y: 125 }));

  const chairs = React.useMemo(() => {
    return [
      p1InitialPosition,
      p2InitialPosition,
      p3InitialPosition,
      p4InitialPosition,
      p5InitialPosition,
      p6InitialPosition,
      p7InitialPosition,
      p8InitialPosition,
    ];
  }, [
    p1InitialPosition,
    p2InitialPosition,
    p3InitialPosition,
    p4InitialPosition,
    p5InitialPosition,
    p6InitialPosition,
    p7InitialPosition,
    p8InitialPosition,
  ]);

  // updated/animated positions

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const np = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < chairs.length; i++) {
      console.log(chairs[i], chairs[(i + shiftBy) % 8]);
      np.push(
        Animated.timing(chairs[i], {
          toValue: chairs[(i + shiftBy) % 8],
          duration: 800,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      );
    }
    Animated.parallel(np).start();

    console.log('');
  }, [shiftBy]);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        onLayout={event => {
          const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          console.log('height:', layout.height);
          console.log('width:', layout.width);
          console.log('x:', layout.x);
          console.log('y:', layout.y);
        }}
        source={require('../../assets/image/table/table.png')}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      />
      {/* p1 */}
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          transform: [{ translateX: p1InitialPosition.x }, { translateY: p1InitialPosition.y }],
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          // disabled={selectedChair}
          onPress={() => setSiftBy(4)}>
          <Icon name="chair" size={30} color="blue" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
      {/* p2 */}
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          transform: [{ translateX: p2InitialPosition.x }, { translateY: p2InitialPosition.y }],
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          // disabled={selectedChair}
          onPress={() => setSiftBy(3)}>
          <Icon name="chair" size={30} color="skyblue" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
      {/* p3 */}
      {/* p4 */}
      {/* p5 */}
      {/* p6 */}
      {/* p7 */}
      {/* p8 */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

this is the link to complete the code for the screen- [snack.expo.dev/sd7yF5CzZ](https://snack.expo.dev/sd7yF5CzZ)

Please help.

Comment: try adding a working code (upload this part into snack) so we can see the problem

Comment: this this the link to complete code for the screen- https://snack.expo.dev/sd7yF5CzZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `useLayoutEffect` in your code :

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const np = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < chairs.length; i++) {
      console.log(chairs[i], chairs[(i + shiftBy) % 8]);
      np.push(
        Animated.timing(chairs[i], {
          toValue: chairs[(i + shiftBy) % 8],
          duration: 800,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      );
    }
    Animated.parallel(np).start();

    console.log('');
  }, [shiftBy]);
```

**Explaination**

Since `useEffect` callbacks are called after the render commit phase and hence after the render cycle, and `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` is meant to "prepare" the next render, it is already too late to call it inside of `useEffect`.

So the solution is to use `useLayoutEffect` along with `useEffect` to ensure that animation will run on first render

Comment: thanks for the answer but sorry it did not worked please suggest something else

Comment: @yogeshkumar what exactly did not work for you ?

Comment: on first click(any chair) code works(as console.log works) but animation does not take place

Comment: @yogeshkumar forgot to tell you that you have to initiate shiftBy by a number > 0, ex: 1

Comment: here's the snack for it https://snack.expo.dev/e_Yki70nv